# is Intel RST needed for computers intended for in-extensive tasks

Tags: intel-rst

Recently i replaced my HDD in my laptop. IAStorDataMgrSvc(Intel Rapid Storage Technology) and its related programs came with the installation. I read this QA http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-5460-program.aspx

I do browsing, programming using IDE's, download large files and watch regional movies form HDD.

I never configured it. I have 500 GB HDD with two partitions. i7 processor.

Do i really need RST?

Answer (score 1):

RST is, more-or-less RAID management.  If you only have a single drive the advantages of RST are likely to be small (some people say it improves the speed a little, but I don't see how, and there are numerous posts saying this is not needed).  This is certainly not something you "NEED"

The best post I found was [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/do-i-really-need-intel-rapid-storage-technology.639071/) - and it says that in a 1 disk configuration it essentially acts as an alternate SATA AHCI controller offering performance and power management for disks - at the expense of utilising memory.